# can't pass text value using ckeditor

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

I am trying to send text value using ckeditor. But i don't get any value from ckeditor. If i use HTML then i get the value. I don't know what i am doing wrong. Please can some one help me. 
Here is my code :

```
<textarea class="ckeditor" id="text" name="text"><?php echo $article['text'];?></textarea>

<input id="articleSUBMIT" type="submit" value="submit" onClick="return articlePOST();"/>
```

Here is my ajax code:

```
function articlePOST(){
    //Is the form valid?
    if($("#article").valid()) {
        var srt = $("#article").serialize();
         $.ajax({
             type: "POST", url: "ajax/article.php", data: srt,
             beforeSend: function(){$("#loading").show("fast");}, 
             complete: function(){$("#loading").hide("fast");},
             success: function(html){$("#article").html(html);$('#uploader-container').html('');}  
          });  
     }  
    return false;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

Use this to save the trigger for all of the editor instances in page:

```
function saveEditorTrigger()
{
  for ( instance in CKEDITOR.instances ) CKEDITOR.instances[instance].updateElement();
}
```

Call this function before you submit. Like this:

```
function articlePOST(){
// Update editor
saveEditorTrigger();

//Is the form valid?
if($("#article").valid()) {
    var srt = $("#article").serialize();
     $.ajax({
         type: "POST", url: "ajax/article.php", data: srt,
         beforeSend: function(){$("#loading").show("fast");}, 
         complete: function(){$("#loading").hide("fast");},
         success: function(html){$("#article").html(html);$('#uploader-container').html('');}  
      });  
 }  
return false;
};
```